# AppEngine backup running wild

Tags: google-app-engine

We have an AppEngine based Python application which has 212 MB of data store data (according to the console).

I tried to do a backup every 10 days.

```
- description: My Backup
  url: /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=BackupToCloud&kind=Application&kind=Design&kind=JobQueue&kind=Journal&kind=License&kind=Token&kind=User&kind=Wiki&filesystem=gs&gs_bucket_name=lpsngbackup
  schedule: every 240 hours
  target: ah-builtin-python-bundle
```

The backup worked successful for several month.

Suddenly thousands of daily /_ah/mapreduce/controller_callback/.... requests are in my logs (our app doesn't do mapreduce).

Where do they come from, how do I stop them?

My bills doubled in the last month.

Comment: google uses mapreduce to parallelize the backup process. datastore errors could delay or affect the backup process and affect billing. see if a datastore issue might have caused the billing spike. sla might reimburse you if so.

Comment: I knew that backup is using mapreduce. I see thousands of these requests. But I don't know where they are coming from or how to stop them. The database is just 212 MB so a backup should be finished in a few seconds. What should I don?

Comment: unsure. all i can think is datastore write failures causing endless retries.

Comment: Today I had 146.500 requests so far (and only 2249 secure requests). We do most of our traffic with SSL. And 143.000 taskqueue calls (we don't do more than 1 task queue call per SSL request). So >140.000 are coming from somewhere else. I had already aborted all backups (there were several in running). But this does not change the requests. How do I stop this?

Comment: I was finally able to stop the requests by pausing the default taskqueue, waiting some time  and than deleting all entries in it before resuming the taskqueue.  A manually started backup hang in 5 of 8 tasks and needed the same kind of stop.